# Mysql Group Data By Time

Tags: php, mysql

Updated Question:

Here is the data

```
   m_to    m_from  m_id    m_time 
        5   5   1   1374769716
        5   5   2   1374771178
        5   5   3   1374771294
        5   5   4   1374771396
        5   5   5   1374771784
        1   5   6   1374772120
        1   5   7   1374773097
        5   1   8   1374773579
        5   1   9   1374774095
        5   1   10  1374774148
        1   5   11  1374777304
        444 5   12  1374779752
        5   444 13  1374780378
        5   5   14  1374781374
        5   5   15  1374832375
        444 5   16  1374837258
        5   444 17  1374837525
        5   444 18  1374838801
        444 5   19  1374838976
        1   5   20  1374842736
        5   5   21  1374842954
        444 5   22  1374843389
        5   5   23  1374843466
        1   5   24  1374843853
        1   5   25  1374848855
        444 5   26  1374848889
        5   5   27  1374848912
        1   5   28  1374849001
        5   5   29  1374849056
        444 5   30  1374850406
```

First coulmn is "m_to" second is m_from and third is m_id and fourht is m_time

Now what I want is, I wanna group by m_from and order by m_time. ut new message which ever wwill be added should be on top and the next row should be on second......etc

I have used.

```
SELECT m_from,m_time FROM messages WHERE m_to='5' GROUP BY m_from ORDER BY m_time DESC
```

but is resuting in something like this

```
444
1
5
```

so, its not correctly sorting data..

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY m_from ORDER BY m_time DESC) as tbl WHERE m_to='XXX' OR m_from='XXX' ORDER BY m_time DESC

Comment: you're using grouping without using any aggregate functions. are you sure you're using `group by` properly? wouldn't just a simple `select * from ... order by m_from, m_time desc` do what you want?

Comment: You cannot do a `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY x` unless * and x are the same.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Quite unfortunately, you _can_ do it in MySQL but you'll often get unreliable results.

Comment: @DavidStarkey yes, you can (in Mysql). Won't debate if this is good, but... possible.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ?? How would that even work?  I'm going to need to test this now.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Because [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is turned off by default. This causes all sorts of problems for people who first learn aggregates incorrectly on MySQL then attempt to work with a different RDBMS.

Comment: I have also used "SELECT m_from,m_time FROM messages WHERE m_to='1' GROUP BY m_from ORDER BY m_time DESC" but it is displaying results but not sorting them, so new message is not on top its in middle or bottom.

Comment: "[the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)"

Comment: You do NOT want to `GROUP BY` anything

Comment: I think you don't need any grouping. See the EDIT part of my answer, maybe.

Comment: What is the output that you want ?

Comment: I have editted the question with full reference and what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue stemming from the `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY`.  [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) allows this to happen, but it can cause some issues.

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate**. Furthermore, **the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause**. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

As far as getting the data you want, I think [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741a5/5) will work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` ORDER BY m_from ASC, m_time DESC
```

If you want it sorted by time first, just move `m_from ASC` to the end

**EDIT**

Given your updated question, this should limit the columns to what you want:

```
SELECT m_from, m_time  FROM `messages` ORDER BY m_from ASC, m_time DESC
```

Comment: What you said? Its not equivalent to my question.

Comment: @AhmedHabib Your question is trying to do a `SELECT *`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`.  This is not allowed in MySQL unless all of * is included in your GROUP BY.  Also, I think * is not what you meant since there seems to be a `m_to` in the query and not the table you provided.

Comment: @AhmedHabib Thanks for the update, but your query says `msg_from` which is not a valid field from your table.

Comment: its m_from sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you're grouping by one(or more) column then you have to do something to all the non-grouped columns in order for your query to make sense.

You have to say what you want done with all the grouped values. Usually something like SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), GROUP_CONCAT()

If you're grouping by m_from, then you won't be able to sort by m_time, as all the records for m_from will be grouped together, and for the non-grouped values you will get an arbitrary answer, since you didn't specify what to do with the group.

You probably want to use an aggregate function, such as MAX(m_time) to get the highest value for m_time, and then sort on that.

I'd suggest something like.

```
 SELECT MAX(m_id),m_from, MAX(m_time) as latest FROM messages 
    WHERE m_to='XXX' OR m_from='XXX' 
    GROUP BY m_from 
    ORDER BY latest DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the m_from that correspond to the last message to appear at the top of the list by doing something like this :

```
SELECT m_from, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
FROM messages 
GROUP BY m_from 
ORDER BY m_time DESC
```

but hard to say without knowing what is the output that you want...

EDIT :

Hope this one will work :

```
SELECT m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
FROM (
SELECT m_from AS m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
 FROM messages 
 WHERE m_to = 5
 GROUP BY m_from
UNION
SELECT m_to AS m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
 FROM messages 
 WHERE m_from = 5
 GROUP BY m_to
 ) AS result
GROUP BY m_user
ORDER BY m_time DESC
```