# mysql grouping and sorting according to time

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem with mysql query, can anybody solve the issue?
Here is the data

```
        m_to    m_from  m_id    m_time 
        5       5       1       1374769716
        5       5       2       1374771178
        5       5       3       1374771294
        5       5       4       1374771396
        5       5       5       1374771784
        1       5       6       1374772120
        1       5       7       1374773097
        5       1       8       1374773579
        5       1       9       1374774095
        5       1       10      1374774148
        1       5       11      1374777304
        444     5       12      1374779752
        5       444     13      1374780378
        5       5       14      1374781374
        5       5       15      1374832375
        444     5       16      1374837258
        5       444     17      1374837525
        5       444     18      1374838801
        444     5       19      1374838976
        1       5       20      1374842736
        5       5       21      1374842954
        444     5       22      1374843389
        5       5       23      1374843466
        1       5       24      1374843853
        1       5       25      1374848855
        444     5       26      1374848889
        5       5       27      1374848912
        1       5       28      1374849001
        5       5       29      1374849056
        444     5       30      1374850406
```

First column is "m_to", second is "m_from" , third is "m_id" and fourth is "m_time"

Now what I want is, I wanna group by m_from and order by m_time. but new message which ever will be added should be on top and the next row should be on second......etc

I have used.

```
SELECT m_from,m_time
FROM messages
WHERE m_to='5'
GROUP BY m_from
ORDER BY m_time DESC
```

but is resulting in something like this

```
444
1
5
```

so, its not correctly sorting data..

Now if new message is added bt 5 then 5 will remain on same position, no change at all. Solve this issue and let me know what am doind wrong here.

Comment: so you want to order by the highest value of m_time for each m_from?

Comment: the sorting is correct since you are ordering by time.

Comment: Yes but m_from should be grouped so it should show only distinct links as 444,1,5 etc

Comment: You have my answer on the same "other" question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885393/mysql-group-data-by-time/17886005#17886005

Comment: I have noticed that 1 last m_id is 28 but it always results in 10.

Comment: ...again...what is the output that you wanted base on those data?

Comment: I want that grouped item should reflect the new added msg by user. I.e. if user 1 add new msg the grouped list should appear as 1 on top then according to m_time next row and then 3rd so on and so fourth,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the m_from that correspond to the last message to appear at the top of the list by doing something like this :

```
 SELECT m_from, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
 FROM messages 
 WHERE m_to = 5
 GROUP BY m_from 
 ORDER BY m_time DESC
```

Result is :

```
5   1374849056
444 1374838801
1   1374774148
```

If I add an entry :

```
INSERT INTO messages
    (m_to, m_from, m_id, m_time)
VALUES
    (5, 1, 31, 1374850416);
```

I now get :

```
1   1374850416
5   1374849056
444 1374838801
```

Which is what you want....you certainly did a mistake somewhere in your test cause IT WORKS FINE!

NEW EDIT :

So, based on what you are now telling, try this :

```
SELECT m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
FROM (
SELECT m_from AS m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
 FROM messages 
 WHERE m_to = 5
 GROUP BY m_from
UNION
SELECT m_to AS m_user, MAX(m_id) as m_id, MAX(m_time) AS m_time
 FROM messages 
 WHERE m_from = 5
 GROUP BY m_to
 ) AS result
GROUP BY m_user
ORDER BY m_time DESC
```

Hope it will works like you want now!

Comment: Your query working fine but when I add new message from 1 user it still displays 
5
444
1
it should display,
1
5
444
as because 1 has added new message

Comment: It's not supposed to since tha MAX(m_time) change after you add an entry, so 1 is suppose to appear on top

Comment: I have checked your code in my query and it didn't worked, also I have sorted ASC but is didn;t helped at all. I don;t understand why but its not working unfortunately.. :(

Comment: SELECT max(m_id),m_from, max(m_time) as max_time from messages where m_to = 5 group by m_from order by max_time desc

But I have got these results from this query,
**max(m_id)  m_from  m_time 
29 5 1374849056
18 444 1374838801
10 1 1374774148**

I wonder why, m_id has different from actual reuslt?? m_id against 444 is 18 but if you see in data it should be 30 as because MAX id for 444 is 30, similarly 1 should have 29 as m_id max value.

Comment: You are mixing your own field.... max(m_id) against 444 AS M_FROM is 18 but max(m_id) against 444 AS M_TO is 30

Comment: Ok its working fine if use 1 send message to user 5 but what if user 5 send message to user 1? its not working in this scenario.

Comment: yes, so that if user 1 send it or user 5 it should be on top. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then this:

```
SELECT m_from, max(m_time) as max_time from messages where m_to = 5 group by m_from order by max_time desc;
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT m_from, max(m_time) as time from messages 
   where m_to = 5 group by m_from order by time desc;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb920/5)

which will give output

```
M_FROM  TIME
 5      1374849056
 444    1374838801
 1      1374774148
```